# Detect Swipe Direction in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Detect Swipe in Cocos2d-x.
How can we find the direction of swipe using CCSwipeGestureRegognizer. 
Find whether we swipe left or right direction on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from its documentation ( [link](https://github.com/spalx/cocos2d-x-extensions/wiki) ) :

In your callback method you should receive a CCObject* parameter, which should be cast to CCSwipe* which has a public memeber `CCSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction;` which I believe is what you need.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used CCSwipeGestureRecognizer then you have added some target method

for example if your target method is Swipe_Action then you will get direction using following code

definition of your method should be

```
void yourclassname::Swipe_Action(CCObject *object)
{

          //get swipe type
if(((CCSwipe*)object)->direction==kSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
//your code here
}
}
```

you can put condition for different swipe type for different result.. hope this helps
Let me know if this dont work.